# How do inputs to UBL::SmoteClassif() influence vectors lengths passed to Fortran?

Tags: r, fortran, smote, oversampling

I'm using UBL::SmoteClassif() function in R to over-sample minority classes to create a more balanced dataset. I have 8 classes. I had a dataset with 357,038 rows and 147 columns/covariates and it works. I have another dataset with 186,274 rows and 186 columns and it produces the following error:

> "Error in neighbours(tgt, dat, dist, p, k) :    long vectors (argument
> 10) are not supported in .Fortran"

Is there a formula I could use where I input the number of columns in the dataset and other parameter settings of the function and it would provide the maximum number of rows the dataset can have for the function to work? This would help me scale my analysis.

Here is a reproducible example that is similar to what I was doing --

```
library(UBL)
library(tidyverse)
test<-data.frame(replicate(186,sample(0:10000,186274,rep=TRUE)),class=c(rep("Class_1",15735),
                                                                        rep("Class_2",3767),
                                                                        rep("Class_3",9874),
                                                                        rep("Class_4",30670),
                                                                        rep("Class_5",1540),
                                                                        rep("Class_6",25109),
                                                                        rep("Class_7",84307),
                                                                        rep("Class_8",15272)))
test<-test%>%mutate(class=factor(class, levels=c('Class_1','Class_2','Class_3','Class_4','Class_5','Class_6','Class_7','Class_8')))
l = list(Class_1 = 1.15, Class_2 = 4.19, Class_3 = 1.55, Class_4=1.00, 
         Class_5=9.81,Class_6=1.04,Class_7=1.01,Class_8=1.00)
datBal <- SmoteClassif(class ~ ., test, C.perc = l)#error

test<-data.frame(replicate(186,sample(0:10000,357038,rep=TRUE)),class=c(rep("Class_1",31878),
                                                                        rep("Class_2",6406),
                                                                        rep("Class_3",31351),
                                                                        rep("Class_4",55430),
                                                                        rep("Class_5",1598),
                                                                        rep("Class_6",32293),
                                                                        rep("Class_7",176013),
                                                                        rep("Class_8",22069)))
test<-test%>%mutate(class=factor(class, levels=c('Class_1','Class_2','Class_3','Class_4','Class_5','Class_6','Class_7','Class_8')))
l = list(Class_1 = 1.14, Class_2 = 4.84, Class_3 = 1.00, Class_4=1.00, 
         Class_5=18.2,Class_6=1.57,Class_7=1.00,Class_8=1.33)
datBal <- SmoteClassif(class ~ ., test, C.perc = l)#this works
```

[Link to SmoteClassif source code](https://ttps://rdrr.io/cran/UBL/src/R/smoteClassif.R)

[Link to neighbors source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/UBL/src/R/Neighbours.R)

[Link to foreign function interface](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Foreign.html)

Comment: 1) It took me a while to get that the code was in R, you may make it clearer at the beginning of your text. 2) without knowing where the Fortran routine is called, what are the arguments, and possibly the Fortran source code, it is difficult to help. 186,274 rows and 186 column is way smaller than the largest 32 integer, event if the array was declared in 1d on the Fortran side, so it's not that simple.

Comment: Thank you @PierU for considering my question. Sorry for not making it clear that I was working in R. I've edited the question like you suggested and for what it is worth I did add links to the source code. Perhaps too tall of an order for fake internet points ;-) I did ask the question on the package github too. I did find out that 150,000 rows and 186 columns works so I'm getting closer to the sweet spot.

Comment: The 10h argument passed to the Fortran routine is `distm`, which is a `nxn` matrix, and `n` is the length of `tgtData`, which is in turn a colum of `Dat`... I assume `n` would be for instance 186,274 in your case ? If yes, I can't see why it is a problem...

Comment: It's helpful to know what the 10th argument is that is causing the problem -- thank you! Makes sense -- I was able to follow along with what you are saying and I'd agree that n would be 186,274 in my case...so I will remain befuddled for now and will report back if I learn any more. Thanks again!